# D3 nesting data with arbitrary depth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js, treemap

I have a data structure that looks like this below and I want to nest it to make a D3 treemap.  I am able to nest it using either `Underscore.nest` or `D3.nest()`.  However, because my data has arbitrary depth, I end up with a bunch of undefined nodes.  How can I nest it to arbitrary depth or `rollup` the undefined nodes?

```
// Example Data 
data = [
    {'name' : 'Post 1', '0' : 'tag_a'},
    {'name' : 'Post 2', '0' : 'tag_b'},
    {'name' : 'Post 3', '0' : 'tag_b', '1' : 'tag_c'},
    {'name' : 'Post 4', '0' : 'tag_d', '1' : 'tag_e', '2' : 'tag_f', '3' : 'tag_g'}
];


// Nesting with the Underscore nest plugin
var underscoreNested = _.nest(data, ['0', '1', '2', '3']);

{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "tag_a",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "undefined",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "undefined",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "undefined",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "0": "tag_a",
                      "name": "Post 1"
                    }
                  ],
                  "index": 0
                }
              ],
              "index": 0
            }
          ],
          "index": 0
        }
      ],
      "index": 0
    }...

// Nesting with D3
var d3Nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d['0']; })
    .key(function(d) { return d['1']; })
    .key(function(d) { return d['2']; })
    .key(function(d) { return d['3']; })
    .entries(data);

[
  {
    "key": "tag_a",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "undefined",
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "undefined",
            "values": [
              {
                "key": "undefined",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "0": "tag_a",
                    "name": "Post 1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice [solution here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/e6ru6-LnOmY) using [burrow.js](https://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/4076122#file_burrow.js).  It works very nicely with the D3 zoomable treemap example.

```
// nest rows with keys array, requires Underscore.js
burrow = function (data) {
  // create simple nested object
  var object = {};
  _(data).each(function(d) {
    var _object = object;
    // branch based on an array of items,
    // with arbitray depth/length,
    // in this case the tags array
    _(d.tags).each(function(element,index) {
      _object[element] = _object[element] || {};
      _object = _object[element];
    });
  });

  // recursively create children array
  function descend(object) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(object)) {    
      var array = [];
        _(object).each(function(value, key) {
          var children = descend(value);
          if (!!children) {
            var branch = {
              name: key,
              children: children
            };
          } else {
            var branch = {
              name: key,
              value: 1
            }; 
          }
          array.push(branch)
        }); // _.each
        return array;
    } // if
    else return false;
  }; // descend

  // nested objectect
  return {
    name: "Nested Data",
    children: descend(object)
  };
};
```